# Trying to connect object when mirrored over center?

Tags: mirror

I am still very new to blender. I am trying to make one connected bit of teeth, but the two faces/edges will not merge at the center of the mirror and I don't know why. the edges seem to connect when I turn off one of the modifiers, but won't once I turn it on again. Please help[image]

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like your teeth have some thickness to them. You might need to remove the face on the side of the teeth you are tryign to connect together. Failing that, try making sure the "merge" checkbox is selected in the mirror modifier

Comment: fixed it! I deleted the face and it connected both sides. Thanks!